# Sum of measures of non-disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am solving problem 3.3.10 from Royden 3rd Edition Real Analysis. The solution manual has a simple, one-line proof for this simple problem, but I had come up with a longer version that involves the definition of measurability.  I think I am using the definition incorrectly--I would greatly appreciate any guidance for future problems.

The problem is to prove that for measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$, $E_1$ and $E_2$, $m(E_1 \cup E_2) + m(E_1 \cap E_2) = mE_1 + mE_2$

Consider the sets of intervals, each generated such that their sum is as small as possible:

$\{I_1\}$ covering $E_1 \backslash E_2$

$\{I_2\}$ covering $E_2 \backslash E_1$

$\{I_3\}$ covering $E_1 \cap E_2$

$\{I_4\}$ covering $E_1 \cup E_2$

Notice that:

$mE_1 = \sum{I_1} + \sum{I_3} $

$mE_2 = \sum{I_2} + \sum{I_3} $

$mE_1 + mE_2 = \sum{I_1} + \sum{I_2} + 2(\sum{I_3})$

$m(E_1 \cup E_2) + m(E_1 \cap E_2) = \sum{I_1} +\sum{I_2} + 2(\sum{I_3})$

Therefore, $m(E_1 \cup E_2) + m(E_1 \cap E_2) = mE_1 + mE_2$

Comment: What do you mean by "their sum is as small as possible"? Doesn't this imply that the measure is zero?

Comment: I am referring to the definition of Lebesgue outer measure; generating a cover of intervals where the sum is as small as possible while still covering the set.

Comment: I think your assuming that you can get a countable collection of intervals such that their lengths equal the measure of the set. But this is not true.Suppose $E_1=\mathbb Q$ and $E_2=\mathbb R$. Then $E_1\cap E_2=\mathbb Q$, which has measure zero. But any collection of intervals covering $\mathbb Q$ will have positive length (although arbitrarily small). You would be better off using finite additivity of measure.

Comment: Also (sorry to be nitpicking) but this -- $mE_1 = \sum I_1 + \cdots$ -- isn't standard notation. You should write $m(E)$ for the measure of a set $E$, and $\ell(I)$ or $l(I)$ for the length of an interval.

Comment: Thank you for the case you mentioned @Trevor, and also for the notation points.

Comment: You are very welcome :) @The_Anomaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're using the definition incorrectly; in general there does not exist a collection of intervals covering a measurable set with the sum of the lengths as small as possible. An infimum is not a minimum.

There are other aspects of your proof that are very curious. You say "notice that" $$mE_1=\sum I_1+\sum I_3.$$ Ignoring problems with the notation: *Why* is that equality valid?

All I can think of is you're claiming the equality holds because $E_1=(E_1\setminus E_2)\cup(E_1\cap E_2)$, so $m(E_1)=m(E_1\setminus E_2)+m(E_1\cap E_2)$. *If* that's the reason, then you're *using* the fact that $m$ is additive on disjoint sets; if you're allowed to use that fact then there's no reason for all the rigamorole with inervals, you can just give a proof based on the measures of various sets.

If that's not your explanation for the equality then what *is* your explanation?

You say you had to come up with a longer version based on the definition of measurability. That makes little sense to me - if you were assigned this task, surely it was actually to prove the result based on the definition of $m$ (???) One could give such a proof, but the above is definitely not it - if my *guess* about what you were asked to do is correct you appear to be using facts (specifically additivity of $m$) that you were not supposed to use.

I'm not sure what the exact problem was, but I'm pretty sure that what you wrote is not a solution.